# How to perform significance test on transition matrices

Tags: fixed-income, credit-ratings, transition-matrix

Say you have in your hand a transition matrix published by Moody, and you also collected the rating information for a sample of bonds, which you use to form your own transition matrix. How can we use our sample to test whether if Moody's transition matrix is correct?

Comment: testing with only one sample is somewhat questionable. How much data do you have ?

Comment: About 1000 bonds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending upon how much data you have, you might find [Violi (2004)](http://www.bis.org/publ/cgfs23violi.pdf) useful.

[Nickell et al. (2000)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.194.3115&rep=rep1&type=pdf), while principally considering time-dependent stability tests, refers a bit to significance testing between the matrices of different agencies and might also provide some insight.